# JSP_Which is better? forwarding request object or forwarding Java Bean?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I am relatively new to Java and JSP.
Currently working on Auth process using JSP and Servlet.

Let's say that I am coding Login process.

In my perspective, I see two ways to do that.

1) Controller forwards the request object from client to DAO or Model class

2) Controller receives the request and put the data(such as ID, PWD) as a form of Java bean and transfer to DAO or Model class.

I've done these two things and both work fine functionally.

So I don't know what's better way to code.

And this makes me wonder another thing.

Is there any drawback if I just forward request from the client not only to login process but also for other whole process?

Comment: Number 2 will be a lot easier to code tests for

Comment: Ideally, you should not pass the request to any layer beyond the Controller. The request object be in Controller itself and use POJO or DTO objects to move your data around across the layers from Controller. Your code may work but that is not the 'way' to do it. You will understand & appreciate why patterns are important when your application grows bigger. It makes life easier & avoids all the mess. And makes the debugging and maintenance a lot more easier.

Comment: @JavaYouth Ok, I saw several examples and it seems that No.1 looks easier for me and was wondering if there is any drawback. I hope that I might figure out 'why' it is better as I study deeper. Thanks.

Comment: @JavaYouth Is it also not recommending to utilize RequestDispatcher? Because I've seen many cases using that library and forward the request to another classes. Even my online teacher does so.

Comment: @KimHyungJune as there was too much to put in the comment. I have consolidated and put as answer

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should not pass the **request** object to any layer beyond the Controller. Let the request object be in Controller itself and use POJO or DTO objects to move your data around across the layers from Controller. Your code may work but that is not the 'way' to do it. You will understand & appreciate why patterns are important when your application grows bigger. It makes life easier & avoids all the mess. And makes the debugging and maintenance a lot easier.

Regarding ***RequestDispatcher***

**RequestDispatcher** is used to forward the request to JSP to render the data where you may need `request parameters` as well as `request attributes` (**example**: list of employees pulled from DB). You actually are forwarding the request object to the JSP. In this case, your request object is still moving around in presentation layer of your application. In fact your JSP will get converted to a Servlet (Controller) by the container later. That's totally fine and these are the two lines that go together:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jspToDisplayAsResponse.jsp"); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

You shaould not pass the request objects to other layers like **Service** layer, **DAO** layer, etc., except for presentation layer which includes your JSPs & Controllers.